# Crapware blocker for Windows

Tags: windows-7, bloatware

Is there a program that runs in a background and prevents installation of crapware (browser toolbars is the first thing that comes to mind)?

Comment: I was thinking of something like http://www.mywot.com/ (Except this is for Web sites). A program like this would come up with a message like "Warning, the Fish tank screensaver you are about to install will display ads/slow down your PC/change your search provider. Do you really want to install it?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the optional daemon named TeaTimer in [Spybot-S&D](http://www.safer-networking.org/) can detect malware in realtime.
[Ad-Aware](http://www.lavasoft.com/index.php) can do that too.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is one, it is called "attention". You should pay attention to the text fields and choices during your installations, then those crapwares have no chance getting on your computer.

Comment: It's hard to install this program into other peoples' minds. Hence the question.

Comment: Sure, you are right, why do so many people use the old brain 0.11 alpha version?

Comment: Or you can call it Burger King.  Your way, right away.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the only way I'm aware of to stop people from installing crapware is to stop them installing anything.  Setting people up as users instead of administrators is a good start unfortunately that means every time they want to install things its you who gets the phone call.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you download software from trusted sources (example: http://download.cnet.com )
2. Programs like Symentec Internet suite has feature of community recommendation which can be bit handy ( as people download and install software they rate the software )
3. Do not blindly click on next->next->next in installation wizard. Lot of time software tells you that it is going to install toolbar or going to download additional software.
4. If customize installation option is available then select that rather than default this gives you more control of your installation.
5. You can use programs that monitor installation so you can revert back if crapware gets installed.
6. You can also use system restore option to revert back the system in case if you notice crapware has been installed.

Comment: So the answer to the question is "Essentially _no_...but you can follow these helpful tips!" :D